# In the text, words of a given length should be replaced with the assigned string(some random words). Output initial text and result

Tags: java, arrays, string

It is forbidden to use regular expression processing tools: java.util.regex package classes (Pattern, Matcher, etc.), as well as methods of the String class (matches, replace, replaceFirst, replaceAll, split). use StringBuilder or StringBuffer. Help do the task.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = new String[4];
        arr[0] = "I";
        arr[1] = "love";
        arr[2] = "orange";
        arr[3] = "juice.";
        System.out.println(arr[0]+" "+ arr[1]+" " + arr[2]+" "+ arr[3]); // I love orange juice
        String randomWord = "crazy impressed of ";
        int givenLength = 4;
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            if (arr[i].length() == givenLength) {
                arr[i] = randomWord;
            }
        }
        String output = String.join(" ",arr);
        System.out.println(output); // I crazy impressed of orange juice
        }
```

I must use StringBuilder and StringBuffer in my code, but i don`t know how to do this. Help me pls. You can use classes

Comment: OK, first let's clarify the assignment: How is a "word" exactly defined? What is meant exactly with "replaced with the assigned number" - assigned by whom to whom? Is this the length? Can you also add an example of input and the expected output. And finally just for clarification: you are allowed to use `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` ?

Comment: @cyberbrain sorry for mistakes, i corrected them and give my code as example, i must use StringBuilder or StringBuffer, one of them, no matter which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "all words like willbereplaced with length like word replacedwillbe";
    int givenLength = 14;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int currentWordLength = 0;
    for(char let: input.toCharArray()) {
        if(' ' == let){
            if(currentWordLength == givenLength) {
                builder.replace(builder.length() - givenLength, builder.length(), getRandom());
            }
            currentWordLength = 0;
        } else {
            currentWordLength++;
        }
        builder.append(let);
    }
    if(currentWordLength == givenLength) {
        builder.replace(builder.length() - givenLength, builder.length(), getRandom());
    }

    System.out.println(input);
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
}

static String getRandom() {
    return Math.random() < 0.5 ? "random1" : "random2";
}
```